# Sampling the Kolmogorov Distribution

Tags: r

How can I generate K-S statistic critical values in R? I am trying to build a table to export for somebody into Excel.

For example, I can run this:

```r
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)

ks.test(x, y)

#   Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
# data:  x and y
# D = 0.38, p-value = 0.001315
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Is there a function I can run such that `f(D = 0.38, n = 50) =  0.001315` and/or one such that `g(q = 0.001315, n = 50) = 0.38`?

I looked in the source code of `ks.test()`  and could not figure it out (I think it deferred to a C internal). I also tried `cont_ks_cdf()` from package `KSgeneral` but I don't think I understand the argument definitions.

Comment: Look at the manual page for `ks.test`. It returns a list containing what you want and more. Specifically: `ks.test(x, y)$statistic` returns .38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is extract the relevant line of code from `ks.test()` (and use `:::` to access a function from within the `stats` namespace):

```r
pfun <- function(D, n1, n2) {
   1- .Call(stats:::C_pSmirnov2x, D, n1, n2)
}
pfun(0.38, 50, 50)
## [1] 0.001314774
```

Then you can use `uniroot()` to get the equivalent `q*` function:

```r
qfun <- function(q, n1, n2, interval=c(0,1e5)) {
   uniroot(function(x) pfun(x, n1, n2) -q, interval=interval)$root
}
qfun(0.05, 50, 50)
## [1] 0.2600097
pfun(0.26, 50, 50)
```

This doesn't quite give back the requested value: I don't know whether the p-value curve is continuous ... ?

Yes: you'll have to be a little careful with definitions

[image: curve of p-value as a function of D]

Comment: The `stats:::` is what I did not realize. Thanks! Do you happen to know if there is an inverse CDF function buried as well?

Comment: Okay, this is very helpful. Thanks for looking into that!