# Get Quantile for Kolmogorov-Smirnov test's critical value

Tags: r, quantile, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am teaching basic statistics, and I have to show step by step how a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is performed. Therefore, I cannot simply do it with one function, like:

```
ks.test(data, distribution)
```

So, I need a quantile function to get the critical value for the test statistic (d) distribution. Does anyone know if such a function exists?

Comment: This sounds complicated for a statistics course at a basic level. This distribution is complicated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66735226/sampling-the-kolmogorov-distribution

Answer (score 0):

I am citing the wiki article on the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution):

> Fast and accurate algorithms to compute the cdf Pr [...] or its complement for arbitrary n n and x x, are available from:
>
> - [C and Java implementations]
> - R implementation: [KSgeneral package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v095i10)

Likely you will find something to calculate a cumulative density function in there. See the [reference manual on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KSgeneral/KSgeneral.pdf).